# powershell to list multiple AD groups membership

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a list of AD groups in a text files adgroups.txt:

Audit
Internal_audit
IT

I want to be able to have a CSV list:

Group Name             Users

Nothing else.  My poweshell script I am using is:

```
$groups = Get-Content c:\temp\ADGroups.txt

foreach($Group in $Groups) {            

Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group | select  @{Expression={$Group};Label="Group Name"},* | Export-CSV c:\temp\GroupsInfo.CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

This spits out WAY to much info.

Group name   Distinguished name    Name     Object Class etc......

Should I use a select-object and only select group name and name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it! Replace the `*` with `name` and it should give you what you are looking for.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Id $Group | select  @{Expression={$Group};Label="Group Name"},Name | Export-CSV c:\temp\GroupsInfo.CSV -NoTypeInformation -append
```

Comment: So close!  Its only showing me the last group name on the list.  it skipped over the other 2...?